# Overlap background image of a HTML table row into the one above

Tags: html, css

Ignore the pretty hideous photos (they're not the actual ones I'll use for the project, just placeholders), but I'm trying to make an HTML email template. I made a perfect template using flexbox (see image below), but have just found out that it is not supported in Gmail, so I have to revert to using an `HTML table`.

My question is that I have a background image that overlaps the content above (using flex), but how can I achieve the same output by using an `HTML table`? Simply, I can go into Photoshop and combine the two images together, but the client doesn't want me to manipulate the images if it can be helped, so doing this through code is the best solution, for now.

[image]

```css
table {
  width: 350px !important;
  max-width: 450px !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

thead,
td {
  text-align: center;
}

#background {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/qsfyckt/Untitled-1.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 100% 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 310px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10000;
  top: -7%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1043506/pexels-photo-1043506.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" style="width: 350px">
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/302899/pexels-photo-302899.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" style="width: 350px"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="background" colspan="2"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/qsfyckt/Untitled-1.png" style="width: 350px"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add styles to the `img`

```
position: relative;
top: -32px;
```